# Just got a MacBook Pro, the calender appointments do not transfer to my iPhone 5 calendar

Tags: macos, applications, calendar

I just got a MacBook Pro laptop and am in early stages of learning.  The calendar that comes with the computer does not transfer the appointments to my iPhone 5S. I could never get Microsoft Outlook calendar to transfer either. What do I need to do to get the transfer to occur?

Comment: at minimum, both signed into the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

On both devices make sure that under iCloud settings Calendars is on. This will ensure that both calendars are syncing with iCloud simultaneously.